# Multilevel dropdown not able to implement using on hover and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to css and trying to create a multilevel dropdown. When I click on the Apparel link, everything under it opens at the same time. I tried with display: none and display: block on hover but, it is not working. Can anyone guide me on this.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}


.navbar-nav:hover .secondDropdown{
  display:block;
}


.navbar-nav .secondDropdown{
  display:none;
}


.navbarDropdown2{
  display:none;
}


.dropdown:hover .navbarDropdown2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apparel </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Girls</a>
        <ul class="navbarDropdown2" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
          <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Girls/Shoes/10015">Shoes</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Boys</a>
        <ul class="navbarDropdown2" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
          <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Boys/Pants/10019">Pants</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the **class names** the first hover dropdown's class name was  `dropdown-toggle` not `dropdown`

Also a codepen link -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReQKJm

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none
}


.navbar-nav:hover .secondDropdown{
  display:block;
}


.navbar-nav .secondDropdown{
  display:none;
}


.navbarDropdown2{
  display:none;
}


.dropdown-toggle:hover .navbarDropdown2 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-item:hover ul{
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Apparel </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu secondDropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Girls</a>
        <ul class="navbarDropdown2" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
          <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Girls/Shoes/10015">Shoes</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Boys</a>
        <ul class="navbarDropdown2" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
          <li class="dropdown-item dropdown"><a href="/Apparel/Boys/Pants/10019">Pants</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Hope it helps you.